# Find number, and remove adjacent characters equal to this number

Tags: perl, unix, sed, awk

Part of my 4 column output looks like this:

```
5    cc1kcc1kc    5    cc1kcc1kc
5    cc2ppggg   5    cc2ppggg
6    ccg12qqqqqqqqqqqqggg    10 ccccg11qqqqqqqqqqqggggg 
3    4qqqqcgc1q   12    cgccgccgccgc
```

I only want the second and fourth columns changed, is there a way with awk/sed to remove the numbers with the characters next to them? 
Or would it be easier/better to use a perl script to perform this transformation?

The resulting output should look like this:

```
5    ccccc    5    ccccc
5    ccggg    5    ccggg
6    ccgggg   10    ccccgggggg 
3    cgc    12    cgccgccgccgc
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Taking the question literally, this removes the next ***n*** characters from fields 2 and 4 for any ***n*** embedded in the field.

```
perl -lane 'for $i (1, 3) {@nums = $F[$i] =~ /(\d+)/g; for $num (@nums) {$F[$i] =~ s/$num.{$num}//}}; print join("\t", @F)'
```

The other answers remove the number and all the characters that follow that are the same.

To illustrate the difference between my answer and the others, use the following input:

```
6    ccg8qqqqqqqqqqqqggg    10 ccccg3qqqqqqqqqqqggggg
```

My version outputs this:

```
6    ccgqqqqggg     10      ccccgqqqqqqqqggggg
```

while theirs output this:

```
6    ccgggg    10 ccccgggggg
```

Answer (score 3):

With `perl`:

```
perl -pe 's/\d+([^\d\s])\1*//g'
```

Comment: +1 because this gets the job done, but a little explanation would be nice.

Comment: Ok. Option `-p` causes Perl to assume the following loop around your code (option `-e` and one-liner), which makes it iterate over arguments somewhat like `sed`. And regexp description see in [answer about `sed`](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11186538/1186729).

Comment: That removes the "10" and "12" which are in column 3 in rows 3 and 4.

Answer (score 2):

With sed:

```
sed 's/[0-9]\+\([a-z]\)\1*//g'
```

The match finds any string of digits (`[0-9]+`) followed by any letter (`[a-z]`). The `\1*` matches any subsequent occurrences of that character. The `/g` (global) modifier makes sure that the replace is done more than once per line.

Answer (score 1):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed 'h;s/\S*\s*\(\S*\).*/\1/;:a;s/[^0-9]*\([0-9]\+\).*/sed "s|\1.\\{\1\\}||" <<<"&"/e;ta;H;g;/\n.*\n/bb;s/\(\S*\s*\)\{3\}\(\S*\).*/\2/;ba;:b;s/^\(\S*\s*\)\(\S*\)\([^\n]*\)\n\(\S*\)/\1\4\3/;s/\(\S*\s*\)\n\(.*\)/\2/' file
```